# gcc generates different results for different filenames

Tags: c, gcc

Why does gcc generate different executables for different sourcefilenames?

to test I have this c-programm called test.c and test2.c:

```
int main(){}
```

"gcc test.c -o test" and "gcc test2.c -o test2" generate different output files. Using a hex-editor I can see that there still is its source-filename hidden in it. Stripping the files still results in different results (the source-filename is gone). Why does gcc operate this way? I tested clang and tcc as well. Clang behaves the like gcc does, whereas tcc generates the same results for different filenames?

gcc version 4.9.1 (Debian 4.9.1-1)

clang 3.4.2-4

tcc version 0.9.25

Comment: I've just checked, and after `strip -s test1 test2` the files are identical (gcc 4.8.2).

Comment: The filenames are placed in the symbol table, but I don't know to what end?

Comment: Same result with gcc 4.9.0 and clang 3.4.2. Can you post your `strip` command?

Comment: I did "strip -s test && strip -s test2". Running on a 64bit linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing a `diff` on the hexdump of both binaries shows a small difference at around offset `0x0280`. Looking through the sections (via `objdump -x`), the differences appear in the `.note.gnu.build-id` section. My guess is that this provides some sort of UUID for distinguishing different builds of otherwise similar code, as well as validate debug info (referenced [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/FeatureBuildId), about a third of the way down).

Comment: You are right. the build-id, when enabled, uniquely identifies each output from the linker. Their main use, that I know of, is to bind the binary to debugging symbols when they reside in a separated file.

Answer (score -1):

The -o option of gcc is to specify the output file. If you give him different -o targets, it will generate different files.

gcc test.c -o foo

And you have a `foo` executable.

Also, note that without a -o option, gcc will output a `a.out`executable.

Comment: OP is asking about differences in file *contents*, not file *names*.